# iOS Rename Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to rename my project but I'm unable to figure out how to rename it where the arrow is pointed. Any help would be appreshated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Where the arrow is pointed" is the *scheme*. To change that name, click on it and choose Manage Schemes. That will give you a dialog where you can select the name and hit Return to edit it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the information. Make the leap from Android to iOS has been interesting.

Answer (score 1):

- Click on the project name
- Select 'New Scheme'
- Create an scheme with desired name
- Click Ok.
- Now, go to manage scheme, and delete the old one.

That's it...